# Conditional formatting Continuous forms

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is it possible to conditionally format individual records in a contimuous form? For example in a list of invoices how can I change the forcolor to red if the invoice has not been paid?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. In fact, that is exactly the sort of thing that the [Conditional Formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/change-the-appearance-of-a-control-by-using-conditional-formatting-HA010208133.aspx) feature was designed to do. See the following Microsoft Office support article for detailed instructions on how to use Conditional Formatting:

[Change the appearance of a control by using conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/change-the-appearance-of-a-control-by-using-conditional-formatting-HA010208133.aspx)

Comment: I do not think this option is available prior to Office 2010.

Comment: @PhilippeGrondier The cited article says that it applies to Access 2007.

Comment: In Form Layout View, the Conditional Formatting option was visble and active, i.e., not "greyed out", but it just would not react when clicked. Same in another database of mine. I have found that I can do what I need with coding in the Form.Detail.Paint Event.

Comment: 2007 then .. autant pour moi